# how to handle cookies in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova

I have developed a phonegap application that has a user login page with a text box for username/password, a check box for "remember my info", and a submit button.

Pretty standard.

When I open it in Firefox, the cookie works fine and my login data is remembered when the box is checked.

However, when using the android emulator, my cookie is not saved, despite "navigator.cookieEnabled" returning true when printed on the emulator for debugging.

I can post the relevant code if needed but my question is more general:

How can you store cookies in android programming using the web based languages that PhoneGap supports? Is it similar to normal web page javascript cookies? Is there a method other than "navigator.cookieEnabled" that will return whether or not cookies are enabled for the android device?

Thanks.

Please give me the solution of this.

Comment: Yes,it is android app

Comment: It is android app,but this is develop through phonegap.In the phonegap we use the javascript and html.

Comment: Take a look at `localStorage`. This is an HTML spec that is used for retaining information. It should work for what you are doing.

Comment: Yes,i know about the local storage.but I want to this with cookies.is there is any way to do this withcookies.

Comment: In the phonegap the coding is done in the javascript.and we make the build for the android using the commands.that command make the apk file of that javascriipt file